# Excel formula for checking multiple conditions and return true/false

Tags: excel, formula

I need to get a formula to check for 2 conditions in Excel.

Under same ID + Software + Dataset1 + Price

if a ID has level 1 and level 2 under same Software, the price for level 1 should be zero cost. Otherwise, level 1 should not be zero cost under same software.

Can someone help on this?

```
+--------+---------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   ID   |   Software    | Dataset1  | Price  | Result  |                                      Comments                                        |
+--------+---------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Alvin  | Orange Level  |        1  |      0 | TRUE    | True because under same software, it has level 2 and therefore level 1 is zero cost  |
| Alvin  | Orange Level  |        2  |    20  | NA      | ignore                                                                               |
| Julie  | Orange Level  |         1 |    10  | FALSE   | False because under same software, it has level 2 so level 1 should be zero cost     |
| Julie  | Orange Level  |        2  |    20  | NA      | ignore                                                                               |
| Jamie  | Orange Level  |        1  |     0  | TRUE    | True because under same software, it has level 2 and therefore level 1 is zero cost  |
| Jamie  | Orange Level  |        2  |    20  | NA      | ignore                                                                               |
| Jamie  | Apple Level   |        1  |    10  | TRUE    | True because under same software, it has level 2 and therefore level 1 is zero cost  |
| Jamie  | Mango Level   |        1  |    10  | TRUE    | True because under same software, it has level 2 and therefore level 1 is zero cost  |
| Steph  | Orange Level  |        1  |     0  | TRUE    | True because under same software, it has level 2 and therefore level 1 is zero cost  |
| Steph  | Orange Level  |        2  |    20  | NA      | ignore                                                                               |
| Steph  | Apple Level   |        1  |     0  | FALSE   | False because under same software, it has level 2 so level 1 should be zero cost     |
| Steph  | Mango Level   |        1  |     0  | FALSE   | False because under same software, it has level 2 so level 1 should be zero cost     |
+--------+---------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Whilst the conversion of the last paragraph to a table is helpful (well done that man!) It is not clear from the table what the rules are to determine the result. One possible interpretation is... For a `(ID, Software)` pair

Comment: Whilst the conversion of the last paragraph to a table is helpful (well done that man!) It is not clear from the table what the rules are to determine the `Result`. One possible interpretation is... For a given `(ID, Software)` pair: if the pair exists with both `Dataset1=1` and `Dataset1=2` then `Result` is TRUE for first instance of pair if its Price is zero and FALSE otherwise; if the Pair exists only with `Dataset1=1` then `Result` is TRUE if Price>0 and FALSE if Price=0. The table doesn't provide examples where the pair only exists with `Dataset1=2`.

Answer (score 0):

To check for more than one condition, use the `AND()` formula.

Example:

```
=AND(1>2; 11<17)
```

returns `FALSE`

```
=AND(1>2; 11<17)
```

returns `TRUE`

Comment: this is only for same row? I need to able to lookout for whole column.

Comment: There's nothing row-specific about it. The examples given here use constants such as `1` for simplicity, but they could equally be something else such as a cell reference or another formula.